# The method presentations.batchUpdate throws "Internal error encountered"

Tags: google-slides-api

I'm working on generation of Google Presentation and sometimes batchUpdate throws the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

[Here's the example of the request body](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/EugeneArol/df8f911c33f8a0f3a7a1a13e72b82b6a/raw/3098ec02c42a2f9aad721a51cfdd40caaf03aaac/body_example.json)

Comment: I posted an answer regarding this. Let me know if that works for you. Tell me if you need further assistance on splitting the request into different calls.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

Your request body is huge. You are requesting many updates in the presentation with a single call. Since you are getting a 500 error, the server is most likely having problems while processing this huge amount of requests.

It's certainly not a question of [write request limits](https://developers.google.com/slides/limits), since you are only making one single (large) write request (and HTTP status is not the appropriate one either).

#### Solution:

In any case, I would suggest you to split your call into as many parts as necessary so that you never get this error. Group the requests into different request bodies and call [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) several successive times. This should fix your problem.

#### Reference:

- [presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [Slides API: Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/slides/limits)
- [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

Comment: I split the request into different calls by 50 instructions(replaceAllShapesWithImage, replaceAllText, replaceText and other) per request, but I still get 500 error.