# Google Slides API batchUpdate Returns 500 Internal Error

Tags: google-slides-api

I am currently doing [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate) request with around 60-70 requests in a single call and I am getting Internal Error (500). Does anyone know what can be the issue?

```
presentations.batchUpdate({
        presentationId,
        requestBody: {
            requests: [{ replaceAllText},{},.......],
        },
    });
```

Error response :

```
[
{
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError"
}
]
```

Comment: Hard to know what's going on with the information provided. Consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Have you checked whether there's a specific request that is failing? Or it just fails when there're many of them? If that's the case, have you checked at which number of requests it is starting to fail?

Comment: thanks, @Iamblichus! Apparently, I couldn't track at which request it's failing but I observed it fails if there are more requests (~>20 requests). i have edited the question with the error i get from the API response when it fails, hope that can help.

Comment: If this error appears every time, worth debugging by removing 1 request per time to locate the failing one, then post minimal example here. Regular practice is to repeat request if it returns 500, but also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60263786/google-slides-api-returning-a-500-server-error?rq=1